# How to check how much InnoDB space is used?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have 20GB `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1`.

How to check how much of this file is really used and how much are junk data which does not store any real data, but just takes space of my disk?

Comment: What makes you think any of that 20 GB is garbage data?

Comment: @Ramhound because sizes of DB dumps are small